# Here im appending table rows which includes comboboxes.How should i get database values into that combo box

Tags: jquery, html, codeigniter

How can iget database values to my jquery generated combobox

```
<script>
 $('#button').on('click', function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#button').on('click', function(){
        $('.tablesaw').find('tbody').append($('<tr><td><select id="heard" class="form-control" name = "fieldname"><option value="0">-- Choose --</option><option value = "Amount">Amount</option></select></td><td><input type  = "text" name = "condition" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></td><td><select id="heard" class="form-control"><option>--Choose--</option></select></td><td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a></td></tr>'));
        $('.e1').select2();
        $('.e2').select2().on('change', function () {
        $(this).next()
            .find('.select2-selection')
            .css({ backgroundColor: this.value });
        }).trigger('change');
    });
});
```

Comment: You could pass data from controller to the view and there include it via php in your jquery

Answer (score 0):

Pass data from controller to view and there display the php values in your javascript generated combobox

For example:

**Controller**

```
class Test extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->db->where('columnname', 'value');
        $query = $this->db->get('tablename');

        $comboboxHtml = '<select id="heard" class="form-control" name = "fieldname"><option value="0">-- Choose --</option>';

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
           $comboboxHtml .= '<option value = "' . $row->optionValue . '">' . $row->optionName . '</option>';
        }

        $comboboxHtml .= '</select>';

        $data = array("view" => "test/index",
                      "comboboxHtml" => $comboboxHtml,
                      "page_title" => "Test");

        $this->load->view('templates/default', $data);
    }
}
```

And then add the data to your Javascript generated combobox like

```
<script>
 $('#button').on('click', function(){
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#button').on('click', function(){
        $('.tablesaw').find('tbody').append($('<tr><td><?php echo $comboboxHtml; ?></td><td><input type  = "text" name = "condition" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12"></td><td><select id="heard" class="form-control"><option>--Choose--</option></select></td><td><a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i> Edit </a><a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete </a></td></tr>'));
        $('.e1').select2();
        $('.e2').select2().on('change', function () {
        $(this).next()
            .find('.select2-selection')
            .css({ backgroundColor: this.value });
        }).trigger('change');
    });
});
</script>
```